# php curl output ehco it self

Tags: php, curl

I have writen a php curl function for downloading a web page from an ssl enable site.
It is no working as I want it to.  It echos itself even if I have not used the echo command elsewhere. 
I want to use this function to save the download page but it saves 1 file not the whole data.

I already googled about this issue but had no success.  Writing on stack overflow is always last option for me and I always avoid due to my bad english as well as bad explanation

```
function gssl($target_url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\ssl\cacert-2019-05-15.pem');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert-2019-05-15.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    $html= curl_exec($ch);
    return $html;
    }

function write($post,$myFile){
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $post);
fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the result of `curl_exec($ch);` not the page from the web site. Use the `CURLOPT_FILE` cURL option to have the returned data put directly into a file.

And, as James said, enable `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` too.

Answer (score 1):

Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true